# Flatten based on disposable key

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

With

`{ _id: "123", super: { super: { super: { someString: "here", someOtherString: "here", someObject: { withSomeContents: true }}}}}`

levels with super keys could be arbitrarily deep, and I'd like every one of them and their contents to be flattened, so as to get

`{ _id: "123", someString: "here", someOtherString: "here", someObject: { withSomeContents: true }}`

What's a good way of doing that? Preferably using underscore.

Comment: Just curious - how did you manage to obtain an object like what we're seeing here?

Comment: Define your problem a little better. So is it only the case that you want properties from the deepest level flatten to the top level? Or are there likely to be other properties at intermediate levels that need to be flattened? Is it possible that some of those property names might clash? How would that be handled?

Comment: define "good way". There's an obvious one that isn't even too long using explicit iteration.

Comment: Why "preferably using underscore"? Is there a particular reason that a vanilla solution can not work for your situation?

Comment: AnotherDev, I hadn't tried much of anything. Wanted to ask for pointers first. @Jan Dvorak, It's using aldeed:simple-schemas (Meteor), in an attempt to add sub/super-schemas. A good way as in elegant, short, clear. Matt Burland, that all levels with a super key be flattened to the top-level. I know from my schemas that there wouldn't be conflicts. Jason C, Preferably using _. for brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to merge the objects recursively, while checking for your desired key:

```js
var data = {
  _id: "123",
  super: {
    super: {
      super: {
        someString: "here",
        someOtherString: "here",
        someObject: {
          withSomeContents: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

function merge(dest, src) {
  Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key) {
    dest[key] = src[key];
  });
}

function flattenKey(data, flatKey) {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce(function(obj, key) {
    if (key === flatKey) {
      merge(obj, flattenKey(data[key], flatKey));
    } else {
      obj[key] = data[key];
    }
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

document.getElementById('r').textContent = JSON.stringify(flattenKey(data, 'super'));
```

```html
<pre id=r></pre>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. Tried searching but wasn't sure if there were some regularly used approaches like a chain in underscore or similar.